# Handle two Queue in Background

Tags: iphone, multithreading, ios7

I am new in Iphone Development and i am working on Threading.

I have created two Queue like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t **Queue1** = dispatch_queue_create("Queue1", NULL);

dispatch_queue_t **Queue2** = dispatch_queue_create("Queue2", NULL);
```

I have added task in Queue1 like this:

```
dispatch_async(**Queue1**, ^{

[self HandleDownloadResponse];

});

dispatch_async(**Queue1**, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});

});
```

When I will get a response of my web service, **Queue1** is executed and it is using Sqllite3 database.

When My data transfer from my device, **Queue2** is executed and it is also used sqllite3.

My Issue is: When I got a web service response first before My data transfer start, I got a database lock error.

So i want to pause(sleep) my **Queue1** when my **Queue2** becomes active.How can i do this?

Comment: try to use a mutual exclusion for accessing to your database. probably it will solve your problem directly.

Comment: I am performing two task ,one for UI Display which read data from Database and other task is performing write operations on Database .so i have used NOMUTEX .

Comment: therefore, your database should be locked while one of the operations is finished, the _mutual exlusion_ (or _lock_, they are the same) could help in this case. probably that would be helpful you to read: https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // response from webservice
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     //insert into database

    }
    }
```

Comment: I can't work on main thread because my main thread working on UI to show data transfer progress.